# PhoneGap/Cordova Application with Google Analytics Plugin error on Android only

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap version 3.3.0-0.18.0

I am using this plugin:

https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin

It works great for iOS, however on Android I cannot seem to log any events, I get the following come up in Eclipse when running on my Android device:

```
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Error on GAThread: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10132 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:667)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:458)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.SimpleNetworkDispatcher.okToDispatch(SimpleNetworkDispatcher.java:69)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.PersistentAnalyticsStore.dispatch(PersistentAnalyticsStore.java:483)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.dispatchToStore(GAServiceProxy.java:245)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.sendQueue(GAServiceProxy.java:216)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy.access$000(GAServiceProxy.java:27)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAServiceProxy$2.run(GAServiceProxy.java:198)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:520)
01-06 11:36:23.705: E/GAV2(3478): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Google Analytics is shutting down.
```

From reading the error messages it seems as though the application does not have permission to send GA data, is there a way round this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below permission to your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

This permission are required to add in every phonegap project. as our html file will run on browser & some of our stylesheet & js needs to check the current state of network. so it can detect that is there any network connection available or not & then it can proceed. To check the state android has the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`
.

Comment: If I edit this within Eclipse, will it not be overwritten each time I run a PhoneGap build, eg `phonegap run android`

Comment: No is the answer to my comment.